# Bash stopped working after touching some files, can I recover from it? (LFS)

Tags: bash, lfs

I am doing as a project for my university; the first phase is to build LFS with some extras; the last requirement I have to meet is to show the prompt, and there I found that I still had to do all the files/directories in chapter 3 of the book: [Chapter3: The Bash Shell Startup Files](https://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable/postlfs/profile.html); so before doing this chapter (luckily) I made a snapshot of the VM just in case. After doing all the steps required, I rebooted the machine and lost the ability to use bash, so obviously I had misconfigured something.

Am I able to recover access to bash or should I return to the snapshot and start again?

In this image the output is in Spanish; but basically says that command was not found.

[image: Picture showing the output of bash every time I try to use a command (output is in Spanish as it is the language configured)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `PATH` is unset for any reason.

To add it again:

```
printf '%s\n' "export PATH='/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin'" >> ~/.bashrc 
source ~/.bashrc
```

Adapt the command if `bash` is not the default shell.

The diagnostic is simple, all built-in commands works, but not those requiring to be e`X`ecutables in `$PATH`